# MWAA Airflow 2.0 in AWS Snowflake connection not showing

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mwaa

Snowflake is not showing in the connections dropdown.
I am using MWAA 2.0 and the providers are already in the requirements.txt
MWAA uses python 3.7 dont know if this can be a thing

Requirements.txt: 
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.0.2/constraints-3.7.txt" 
asn1crypto 
azure-common

azure-core

azure-storage-blob

boto3

botocore

certifi

cffi

chardet

cryptography

greenlet

idna

isodate

jmespath

msrest

numpy

oauthlib

oscrypto

pandas

pyarrow

pycparser

pycryptodomex

PyJWT

pyOpenSSL

python-dateutil

pytz

requests

requests-oauthlib

s3transfer

six

urllib3

apache-airflow-providers-http

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake

#apache-airflow-providers-snowflake[slack]

#apache-airflow-providers-slack

snowflake-connector-python >=2.4.1

snowflake-sqlalchemy >=1.1.0
\

Comment: This might be worth to have a look: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-create-update-environment.html#t-requirements

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is in this trouble, instead of choosing Snowflake in the dropdown, you can choose AWS as the connection and will work fine.

Comment: this is a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to finally figure this one out after trying many different parameter combinations.

My full Snowflake URL is:

```
https://xx12345.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com
```

The correct format for the Host field is:

```
xx12345.us-east-2.snowflakecomputing.com
```

For the Extra field, this is what worked for me:

```
{
    "account": "xx12345.us-east-2.aws",
    "warehouse": "my_warehouse_name",
    "database": "my_database_name"  
}
```

Make sure you put `Amazon Web Services` for the Conn Type, like @AXI said.

Also, I have these modules defined in my requirements.txt file:

```
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==1.3.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.4.5
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
```

My Airflow version is `2.0.2`.

Comment: Amazon Web Services connection type includes AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key. How do I get this from the Snowflake?

Answer (score -1):

According to [MWAA docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-apache-airflow-202.html#missing-snowflake), it should be enough to add `apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==1.3.0` to the requirements file. When I added it to the existing MWAA env, where I had already tried many different combinations of packages, it helped partially. It was possible to create a connection using CLI, but not with UI.

But, when I created a new clean MWAA env with the requirements file as stated in mentioned AWS doc, it worked well. The connection was available in UI.